# Converting from ASCII back to char

Tags: c++, string, char, ascii

I have a function that already converts a string to ASCII ints, but how to I do the reverse? Thanks

Comment: What's an "ASCII int"? Do you mean literal `int` in an array or vector of some sort? ASCII by definition only requires `unsigned char` to store it, it's purely an 8-bit representation.

Comment: What's "the reverse"? What format is the input in? Seems like a trivial problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide an example of the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You question is not clear. Giving you solution based on assumption that your ASCII ints (in your terms) stored in a `vector<int>`

Below function will convert it into string:

```
std::string
AsciiIntToString ( std::vector<int> const& ascii_ints ) 
{
    std:: string ret_val;
    std::vector<int>:: const_iterator it = ascii_ints. begin ();
    for ( ; it != ascii_ints. end (); ++it ) {
        if ( *it < 0 || *it > 255) throw std::exception ("Invalid ASCII code");
        ret_val += static_cast<char>(*it);
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples that convert between number and the textual representation of the number in binary format using `std::bitset` (only works for character sets that can be represented by 7 bits (as US-ASCII for example)):

```
char c = 'a';

// char to int.
int i = static_cast<int>(c);
// int to string (works for char to string also).
std::string bits = std::bitset<8>(i).to_string();

// string to (unsigned long) int.
unsigned long ul = std::bitset<8>(bits).to_ulong();
// int to char.
c = static_cast<char>(ul);
```

Comment: There's nothing here that depends on ASCII. It does assume, though, that characters can be represented in 7 bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's why it can't be used to e.g. transform a `bitset` containing a character from some extended set using more than 7 bits into a `char`. Standard ASCII-character set using 7 bits should be ok though.

Comment: The point is that ASCII is not the only character set that can be represented in 7 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way!

```c++
void convertToString()
{
    char redo;
    int letter;
    int length;

    do{
        cout<< "How long is your word \n";
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Type in the letter values \n";

        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            cin >> letter;
            cout << char (letter);
        }

        cout << "\n To enter another word hit R" << endl;
        cin >> redo;
    } while (redo == 'R');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the neologism "ASCII 'int'" was an imprecise--but not an unclear--reference to ASCII codes. The reference was clear because all of the ASCII codes are whole numbers, just like integers.

The original poster was able to translate an ASCII character into decimal, presumably using a function.

In MySQL, this would be: SELECT ASCII('A') [FROM DUAL];, which returns 65.

To reverse direction, use the char() function:
SELECT CHAR(65) [FROM DUAL];

Perhaps this would be a good work-around for you.

I would recommend using non-GUI client.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure there's much point in giving a MySQL-specific (or even SQL) answer to a C++-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to convert `static` to `cast` is

```
int it=5;
char W = static_cast<char>(*it);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to store it in a char variable:

```
//Let's say your original char was 'A'...
int asciivalue = int('A');

// Now asciivalue = 65

//to convert it back:
char orig = asciivalue;

cout << orig << endl;
```

It'll output 'A'.